# How can I get the category ID by the name?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to have my Discord bot in 2 servers and I want that if someone wants to create a ticket it should create it in the category: Ticket

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all channels the client is currently handling with `client.channels`. On the cache of channels (which is a collection) you can use the `.find()` method to find the channel by its name:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {

  // check command, etc. 

  const channel = await client.channels.cache.find(
    (ch) => ch.name === 'ticket',
  );

 console.log(channel.id);
});
```